# Laravel Hiding Validation Errors Message with Ajax when is true

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel

i have implement the validation errors message with ajax successfully, but when the previous input form is true, the previous error in that input form is not hiding. Anyone can help me to hide the previous error if input form is true?

This is my javascript code :

```
$.ajax({
        url: `${window.url}/income`,
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            _token: CSRF_TOKEN,
            detail: arrValues,
            data_contact_id,
            total,
            description,
            invoice,
            transaction_date,
            to_account_id,
        },
        dataType: "JSON",
        success: function (response) {
            console.log(response);
            if (response.status) {
                Swal.fire({
                    icon: "success",
                    type: "success",
                    title: response.message,
                    showConfirmButton: true,
                }).then((result) => {
                    window.location.href = `${window.url}/income`;
                });
            }
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(jqXHR);
            let fields = [
                "data_contact_id",
                "invoice",
                "transaction_date",
                "to_account_id",
                "description",
            ];

            fields.map((field) => {
                $(`#${field}`).removeClass("is-invalid");
                $(`.${field}-error`).html(``);
            });

            let errors = jqXHR.responseJSON.errors;
            $.each(errors, function (key, value) {
                $(`#${key}`).addClass("is-invalid");
                $(`.${key}-error`).append(`
                <span class="text-danger" style="font-size: 0.8rem">
                    ${value.map((v) => "<strong>" + v + "</strong><br>")}
                </span>
                `);
                console.log("Field : ", key);
            });
            Swal.fire({
                icon: "error",
                type: "error",
                title: "Error!",
                showConfirmButton: true,
            });
        },
    });
```

In my controller i have return validation error json from Validator::make()

```
if ($validator->fails()) {
       return response()->json(['errors' => $validator->errors()->all()]);
}
```

Comment: Please post your full JavaScript form submit code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$.ajax({
  beforeSend: function(){
    $(".key_of_form").removeClass("is-invalid");

    $(".error_of_key").empty();
  },
  complete: function(){
   // Handle the complete event
  }
  error : function(){
    // Handle the error event
  }
  
   // ......
 });
```

`` $(`#${key}`) `` add class `key_of_form`

`` $(`.${key}-error`) `` add class `error_of_key`

`before submit` of form or `beforeSend` of ajax you need reset error messages same as :

`$(".key_of_form").removeClass("is-invalid");`

`$(".error_of_key").empty();`